# Como copiar contenido de un div a otro div al presionar un boton con react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from  "react"
const number=['(', ')','<-',"+", '1', '2', '3',"-", '4', '5', '6',"*", '7','8', '9',"/", 'C', '0', '.', "="]



export default function Numbers(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState(['0']);
    const [numbers] = useState(number);
   
    const copy= ()=>{
        if(value!=='0'){
            setValue('0')
        }else{
            setValue(numbers)
        }
        
    }    
    useEffect(()=>{}, [value])

    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="Text" >{value}</div>
            <div className="Digits">
                {number.map((number)=><bottom onClick={copy} ><div className="Number" >{number}</div></bottom>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

La idea es que al presionar el cualquier boton, el contenido del div con className "Number" se copie al setValue asi actualizarlo en un div nuevo, para eso uso useState para actualizar el value, y el useEffect para que renderice cada vez que cambie el value.

Comment: Lo que buscas es que cada vez que el usuario de click en el `botón`, su valor proveniente de `number` aparezca en  `<div className="Text" >{value}</div>` ¿Puedes confirmar? saludos

Comment: exactamente, bueno lo solucione agregando esta función al botón onClick={()=>copy(number)}, solo me falta que se agrupe en una array en el div

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div className="Digits">
                {number.map((number)=><bottom onClick={()=>copy(number)} ><div className="Number" >{number}</div></bottom>)}
            </div>
```

se agrega la función copy en el onClick

```
const copy=(number)=>{
        if(value!=='0'){
            setValue('0')
        }else{
            setValue(number) 
        }
```